# I need to analyze the tables in the database ( ORACLE 11g )

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to analyze the tables in the database.  I would like to know which data we haven't read in particular tables for a long time.

1. Last time I did SELECT data from the table that were added on the day ....
2. Last time I did UPDATE data that were added on the day ....
3. Last time I did INSERT to the table on the day ....

What DBA tables do I need to select to extract such data?

Comment: You ought to check if your [database audit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50521) is enabled. Otherwise you have no chance for 1).  2) and 3) can be answered if you have trigger or application maintained `create`and `modify` timestamps in each table.

Comment: Expanding on @MarmiteBomber's comment: if you only want to know when the last activity on the tables were, without knowing specifically when each row was modified, you could create a separate table with e.g. columns `OWNER`, `TABLE_NAME`, `LAST_INSERT_DT`, `LAST_UPDATE_DT` and use an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` statement trigger on each target table to maintain your stats table. For SELECTs, though, auditing is the only way I can think of. Note that this will negatively affect performance, and the impact can only be determined after you've implemented it.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Creating a separate table is not an option because I have to do an analysis of the tables I have. We have a database that has hundreds of columns and some data have not been extracted for years. Inserts for most of them are still done but the old data I have to move to another TABLESPACE and compress.

Comment: OK. The database does not maintain this kind of information for you *unless* database auditing is enabled, as per @MarmiteBomber's comment. Hopefully you have that to work from.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica if there are any data in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL it means that the audit is enabled ?

Comment: Long shot, very long shot. Try looking in `dba_hist_sqlstat` , `dba_hist_snapshot` and `dba_hist_active_sess_history` .